# Erratic search results from Elastic when sorting on a field

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We just upgraded to Elasticsearch 2.3.1 (from 1.7) and we're getting strange search behavior that I can't explain. What seems to happen is that a search request containing a `bool` query and a `sort` clause is returning:

1. Documents that don't seem to match the given search terms in any way.
2. Wildly different estimates on the `total` of matching documents each request

A minimal example of a request with this behavior:

```
post pim_search_1/_search
{
   "explain": false,
   "track_scores": false,
   "sort": [
      {
         "product_id": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "publication": [
                     "public"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "query_string": {
                  "query": "iphone",
                  "default_operator": "and"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

So in this case, a query string for "iphone" returns no iPhones at all. Setting `explain` to true yields this for the documents that appear to have no matching terms at all:

```
 "_explanation": {
           "value": 0,
           "description": "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
           "details": [
              {
                 "value": 0,
                 "description": "no match on required clause (#ConstantScore(publication:public) #_all:iphone)",
```

So the document has no matching clauses, but it's still returned?

We've found two workarounds for this behavior:

1. Sort on `_score` or leave out the `sort` clause entirely. Sorting on anything else, like the field above or on `_doc` gives the wonky behavior.
2. Include `track_scores : true` on the request.

So it appears to have something to do with scoring and relevancy. But since we're sorting on a field of our own, we're not interested in relevancy or score. Without the workarounds, the `max_score` on the response is `null` and so is the `_score` of every document.

Is this behavior something that can be explained in any way, or should we be looking at cluster health/configuration/corruption? According to the cluster, its health is green and all shards for this index appear healthy. It's currently a small index with 3 shards (1 replica per shard) over 3 nodes.

## Update

I've further investigated the issue and it seems cache related. Specifically, the fielddata cache for the `_all` field (I'm not very familiar with the internals of Elasticsearch, so please correct me if that's not a thing).

### Steps to reproduce

I have a data set that reproduces the problem, leave a comment and I can send it to you.

Use the following query:

```
post pim_search_1/_search
{
   "fields": [
       "_all"
   ],
   "explain": true,
   "size": 100,
   "sort": [
      {
         "product_id": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "_all", 
                  "query": "surface",
                  "default_operator": "and"
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "publication": [
                     "public"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }  
   }
}
```

1. Execute the query. You're searching for "surface" in the query string here and this should result in 22 hits total. This is correct. Execute this query a bunch of times (this seems to matter for step 2).
2. Change the query string to "iphone". This will result in 22 hits still, even though the dataset contains only one item that should match. The `_explanation` also mentions that the found documents don't actually match, like my example above.
3. Execute this: `post pim_search_1/_cache/clear`
4. Execute the query again for "iphone". It should now only return 1 hit, which is correct. Also execute this one a bunch of times.
5. Execute the query again for "surface", this will now return only 1 hit and again the `_explanation` states that it didn't get a match on the resulting document.
6. Remove the `sort` clause from the query and everything appears normal. The same is true for including `"track_scores" : true`.

Instead of `_cache/clear` it also works to just restart the cluster.

I say it's related to the `_all` field because changing the `default_field` of the `query_string` to the `primitive_name` field (an analyzed field) results in the correct behavior. For this example, I've made `_all` a stored field (it isn't normally with us) and it's returned in the search results so you can inspect it (doesn't appear to contain anything weird).

The above was done on a single node cluster (my local PC) on Elasticsearch 2.3.5.

[This](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13662) Github question seems to be about the same issue as mine, but could not be reproduced at the time and was closed.

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible example of the behaviour?

Comment: @RussCam - I've tried creating a new index and data from scratch, but could not recreate the problem. I've now taken our index and deleted all documents that weren't relevant for this problem and I've been able to reproduce the issue that way. I can send you the data but rather not publicly so you can message me on Twitter `@queryable` and I can send you the index data. I'm also going to update this post with some more details I found.

Comment: Thanks @JulianR, will PM you on twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Elasticsearch 2.4:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20196